# show/hide divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to write a function, preferably in jQuery that allows to display a div with description of a corresponding item.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<img src="img1.png" id="img1">

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
description 1
</div>

<img src="img2.png" id="img2">

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
description 2
</div>

<img src="img3.png" id="img3">

<div id="div3" style="display:none">
description 3
</div>
```

Clicking on image1 should display div1. There can be only one div open at a time. But I think jQuery is the best route to take to solve this. Now sure how it is done...

Comment: How do I do it if I create a list of images and divs dynamicaly, therefore do not have a Name or ID for sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#img1').click(function(){
     $('#div1').show();//or use .toggle() to show/hide
  });
});
```

If you're always just toggling the *next* div after an image, give the images and divs classes, and handle it generically.

```
Ex: <img class="toggleImage"/><div class="toggledDiv"></div>

$('.toggleImage').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.toggledDiv').toggle();
});
```

And to ensure that only one div is open at a time, do this:

```
$('.toggleImage').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.toggledDiv').hide();
  $(this).next('.toggledDiv').show();
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I modified $(this).next('.toggledDiv').toggle(); and it works great to open/close div. I do, however have an issue with closing siblings... It does not seem to work... Not sure why.

Comment: Returned back to $(this).next('.toggledDiv').show(); but still have issue with $(this).siblings('.toggledDiv').hide(); -- does not seem to work...

Comment: Hmm. Try  $('.toggledDiv').parent().children('.toggledDiv').hide();

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Here's a working example using siblings: http://jsfiddle.net/mn7xp/

Comment: That worked! I was afraid that it'll close ALL divs, but since it opens the right one in the next line -- it worked! Great suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#img1').click(
       function() { 
          $('#div1').toggle(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event to the image that shows the div.

```
$("#img1").click( function() {
     $("#div1").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `show()` method that you can use to show a particular item.

If you want to be able to show/hide based on context you can use `toggle()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("img").bind("click", function(){
  var divid = $(this).attr(id);
  divid = divid.replace("img","div");
  $("#"+divid).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Putting data in the ID is a terrible, terrible idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
function showOnly(inDiv)
{
   $("#div1").hide();
   $("#div2").hide();
   $("#div3").hide();

   $(inDiv).show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#img1").click(showOnly("#div1"));
  $("#img2").click(showOnly("#div2"));
  $("#img3").click(showOnly("#div3"));
});
```

There are ways to do this with a list, or using wild cards for the id number -- but I'm sure this will get you going in the right direction...

Comment: The variable and function names don't make sense, the code duplication is sloppy, and the suggestion to use wild cards and sequential ids is pretty bad.